# I can't get media queries to work properly inside a styled component div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components

I'm using **styled component** in this project. everything worked fine but when it comes to make this website responsive it just does not respond.
Here an example (I'm trying to remove all navLinks when the window is less than 375px)[ie: display: none not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgJuH.png)

This is my imported media query from styled component inside responsive.js

```
import {css} from "styled-components";

export const mobile = (props) => {
    return css `
         @media only screen and (max-width: 375px){
            ${props}
        }
    `;
};
```

here is the code inside Navbar.jsx

```
import styled from'styled-components'
import { mobile } from '../responsive'
```

```
const LinkNav = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    ${mobile({display:"none"})}
`
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't appear in dev tools at all?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example you provided but everything seems to work fine, could you be more specific with your question?

```js
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const responsiveStyle = (prop) => css`
  @media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    ${prop}
  }
`;

export const StyledApp = styled.main`
  ${responsiveStyle({ background: "red" })}
`;
```

Result:
[responsive style works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilej4.png)